# Creating a class that generates a card

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a class called Card, it will deal one card (random), with then deal method, it will deal one card using random, than I will define face_value that will return the value for the card object for example: 1 = one, 12 = queen. Here is how it looks so far. I'm a little confused how creating a class works, can somebody explain this to me? because the book just confuses me even more.

```
    import random
class Card:
def __init__(self):
    self.__value = 0

def deal(self):        
    self.__value = random.randint(1,13)        



def find_face_value(self):


    if value == 1:
        print ("Ace")      
    elif value == 2:
        print ("Two")
    elif value == 3:
        print ("Three")
    elif value == 4:
        print ("Four")
    elif value == 5:
        print ("Five")
    elif value == 6:
        print ("Six")
    elif value == 7:
        print ("Seven")
    elif value == 8:
        print ("Eight")
    elif value == 9:
        print ("Nine")
    elif value == 10:
        print ("Ten")
    elif value == 11:
        print ("Jack")
    elif value == 12:
        print ("Queen")
    elif value == 13:
        print ("King")
    else:
        # This will catch any invalid card values
        print ("Invalid card")
    return self.__value
```

This is the second program to test it:

```
 import classcard



pla = classcard.Card()

print(pla)
```

Comment: "a class called Card, it will deal one card (random)"... This is confusing; is your class meant to represent a card, or a deck of cards?

Comment: one card from a deck of cards

Comment: One card without a suit.

Answer (score 0):

You're off to a good start! You want to create the random card value when you initialize the object (because that's what initializing is for), and you don't want to have a `deal` function in your Card class, because that's meant for decks. I'd also recommend having a **list** of values instead of a collection of if-elif statements. Finally, there's a specific method for printing out the status/value/state of an object: the string method `__str__(self)`.

```
import random
class Card:
  def __init__(self):
    self.value = random.randint(0,12)
    self.suit = random.randint(0,3)
    self.names = ['Ace', 'Two', 'Three', ..., 'Ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
    self.suitNames = ['Spades', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs', 'Hearts']

  def  __str__(self):
    card = self.names[self.value] + 'of' + self.suitNames[self.suit]
    return card

>>>
>>> temp = Card()
>>> print(temp) # 'Two of Clubs'
```

This remains untested, but you get the general idea.
BTW, self is needed for pretty much everything.

Comment: I would suggest to put the `self.names` and `self.suitNames` as class variables instead of instances variables, since they are common to the class and not to the instance and define an attribute `self.name = ' '.join([self.names[self.value], 'of', self.suitNames[self.suit]])`, so that `__str__` just needs to return `self.name`.

Comment: okay, so how would this look on the program that will execute it?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to separate the representation of a `Card` object from the production of a random `Card`.
Here is an approach where class variables are used to specify the `str` representation:

```
import random


class Card:

    VALUES = {'1': 'Ace', 'A': 'Ace', 'J': 'Jack', '11': 'Jack', 'Q': 'Queen', '12': 'Queen', 'K': 'King', '13': 'King'}
    SUITS = {'H': 'hearts', 'S': 'spades', 'D': 'diamond', 'C': 'clubs'}

    def __init__(self, value, suit):
        self.value = str(value)
        self.suit = suit

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{Card.VALUES.get(self.value, self.value)} of {Card.SUITS[self.suit]}"


def get_random_card():
    return Card(random.randrange(1, 14), random.choice(list(Card.SUITS.keys())))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    for _ in range(10):
        print(get_random_card())
```

#### output example:

```
Ace of clubs
10 of hearts
3 of spades
2 of spades
8 of diamond
Ace of hearts
2 of clubs
Ace of spades
8 of diamond
Jack of hearts
```

#### Note:

This example draws cards from an infinite deck. i/e the same card can be generates many times.

If you wanted to limit the cards drawn to a number of decks, you could use a `Deck` class; maybe like this:

```
class Deck:
    """represents a deck of 52 cards or a multiple of 52 cards"""

    def __init__(self, num_decks=1):
        self.cards = [Card(val, suit) for val in range(1, 14) for suit in list(Card.SUITS.keys()) for _ in range(num_decks)]
        self.num_decks = num_decks
        self.shuffled = False

    def __iter__(self):
        for card in self.cards:
            yield card

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)
        self.shuffled = True

    def get_random_card(self):
        """removes a random card from the deck and returns it
        shuffles the deck if not already shuffled"""
        if not self.shuffled:
            self.shuffle()
        return self.cards.pop()


def get_random_card():
    return Card(random.randrange(1, 14), random.choice(list(Card.SUITS.keys())))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    deck = Deck(3)   # creates a Deck that holds 3x52 cards
    deck.shuffle()

    for idx, card in enumerate(deck):
        print(idx, card)
```

From there, it is easy to add functionality that will deal hands from a deck to various players.